# How to use the 3rd-party modules in a serverless application?

Tags: node.js, serverless, cloudflare-workers, wrangler

I'm new to serverless, and I want to deploy my project on **Cloudflare Workers**. I have read the docs but I couldn't find any useful infomation. I have no idea about this. Please help me!!!

For instance, I want to use the [nanoid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid) and return the value. What should I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.